# make automatic update

Tags: android

is there any way to find out  new version of application is available on android market and download it automatically and install it automatically ,

I do not mean I check my web site to know new version is released , I mean android market 
thanks

Comment: You might want to try http://android.stackexchange.com for this one. SO is for *programming* questions only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that can only be done by the user checking the allow automatic updates when they get your app.